# How to update multidimensional array value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to update second item of the first child array in a multidimensional array

**Example Array:**

```
$cars = array
(
 array("Volvo",10),
 array("BMW",10),
 array("Saab",10),
 array("Land Rover",10)
);
```

i want to replace "20" instead "10" from first array

**Result:**

```
$cars = array
(
 array("Volvo",20),
 array("BMW",10),
 array("Saab",10),
 array("Land Rover",10)
);
```

Comment: `$cars[0][1] = 20;`

Comment: @quentino is correct. That's the right answer to your question. But, so you know, if there is just one number for every car type, you could have used $cars = array("Volvo" => 20, "BMW" => 10... etc. );  And then you would have been able to change it by using $cars["Volvo"] = 20; (search for associative arrays in php)

Comment: @quentino this is returns like this- [["volvo",10],{"1":20}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use indices :

```
$cars[0][1] = 20;
```

Will update the second value (`[1]`) of the first array (`[0]`).

Full code :

```
$cars = array
(
 array("Volvo",10),
 array("BMW",10),
 array("Saab",10),
 array("Land Rover",10)
);
$cars[0][1] = 20;
print_r($cars);
```

outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Volvo
            [1] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => BMW
            [1] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Saab
            [1] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Land Rover
            [1] => 10
        )

)
```

Comment: this is returns like this- [["volvo",10],{"1":20}]

Comment: @RafeeqMohamed Please check the updated answer with full code.

Answer (score 1):

As you know that you are dealing with multidimensional array. So, try to find out which data you are trying to update. you want to update first array's second value.
Array generally starts from index zero. That's why if you want to update you need to go at $cars[0][1] position.

```
 $cars = array(
 array("Volvo",10), //position $cars[0]
 array("BMW",10), //position $cars[1]
 array("Saab",10), //position $cars[2]
 array("Land Rover",10) //position $cars[3]
);
```

as first index is built with two data. then you should choose $cars[0][1] for updating data and reach at 20.so update data like below

```
$cars[0][1] = 10;
```